# hide/remove header and footer

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How I want remove header and footer in SSRS for the last 6 page.

Thank You

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You cannot conditionally remove the footer or header. The only option is to control visibility of header and footer elements based on page number.

Comment: how to control the visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element in your header or footer, whether it be an image or a text box or anything else, right click on each item and select the 'properties' option at the bottom of the menu. Then select the 'visibility' tab and change from 'show' to 'show or hide based on an expression'. Click the button with a 'fx' icon, and then enter the following expression

[image]

```
=Switch(Globals!PageNumber > 2,true)
```

This will remove the selected element from the header or footer if page number is greater than 2. So in this case if your report is 5 pages long, pages 3, 4 and 5 will not include the selected element. Adjust this based on your requirements.

Comment: the problem is how to control visibility for example the 6 last pages...means the earlier page is not fixed maybe 1 page or more..thankyou in advance